# Mesmo sem dar erros, as informações não são salvas no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando criar um sistema de registro utilizando classes, meu código não aparece nenhum erro, entretanto ainda assim as informações não são salvas no banco de dados.

Eu não consegui encontrar o problema, caso alguém possa me ajudar eu agradeço

```php
class Usuario {

    private $pdo;

    public function conectar($dataBase, $host, $user, $password) {
        global $pdo;
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$dataBase.";host=".$host, $user, $password);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            throw new PDOException($e);
        }
    }

    public function cadastrar($nome, $sobreNome, $email, $telefone, $senha, $codigo, $level = 5) {

        global $pdo;
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE Email = ?");
        $sql->execute(array($email));

        if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
            return false; //email já cadastrado
        } else {
            //email não cadastrado, então cria uma função para cadastrar
            $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (Nome, SobreNome, Email, Telefone, Senha, codigo, Level) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $sql->execute(array($nome, $sobreNome, $email, $telefone, $senha, $codigo, $level));
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

```php
$conn = new Usuario();
$conn->conectar("codigo_util", "localhost", "root", "");
$cadastro = new Usuario();
$cadastro->cadastrar($_POST['nome'], $_POST['Sobrenome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['telefone'], $_POST['senha'], $_POST['codigo']);
```

> Edit

Refiz todo o código usando as dicas que vocês deram, e o problema foi solucionado, muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou deixar o código abaixo caso alguém precise.

```
class Usuarios {

    private $pdo;

    public function __construct($dataBase, $host, $user, $pass) {
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$dataBase.";host=".$host, $user, $pass);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function cadastrar($nome, $sobreNome, $email, $telefone, $senha, $codigo, $level = 5) {
        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE email = ?");
        $sql->execute(array($email));
        if($sql->rowCount() < 1) {
            $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (Nome, SobreNome, Email, Telefone, Senha, CodigoRegistro, Level) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $sql->execute(array($nome, $sobreNome, $email, $telefone, $senha, $codigo, $level));
        } else {
            echo "Email já existente";
        }
    }
}

$cadastro = new Usuarios("codigo_util", "localhost", "root", "");
$cadastro->cadastrar($_POST['nome'], $_POST['Sobrenome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['telefone'], $_POST['senha'], $_POST['codigo']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou achando a declaração da classe estranha.
Começando pela variavel `$pdo`, esta é um atributo da classe e também uma variável global :/

minha sugestão é reescreve a classe dessa maneira para evitar problema:

```php
Class Usuario {
  private $pdo;

  public function __construct($dataBase, $host, $user, $password) {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$dataBase.";host=".$host, $user, $password);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        throw new PDOException($e);
    }
  }

  public function cadastrar($nome, $sobreNome, $email, $telefone, $senha, $codigo, $level = 5) {

    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE Email = ?");
    $sql->execute(array($email));

    if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
        return false; //email já cadastrado
    } else {
        //email não cadastrado, então cria uma função para cadastrar
        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (Nome, SobreNome, Email, Telefone, Senha, codigo, Level) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        try {
           $sql->execute(array($nome, $sobreNome, $email, $telefone, $senha, $codigo, $level));
           return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
           error_log($e->getMessage());
           return false;
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Agora você pode chamar a classe assim:

```
$cadastro = new Usuario("codigo_util", "localhost", "root", "");
$cadastro->cadastrar($_POST['nome'], $_POST['Sobrenome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['telefone'], $_POST['senha'], $_POST['codigo']);
```

Espero que isso te ajuda com o seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Você está misturando a propriedade privada $pdo com global $pdo.

Dentro do método cadastrar() , utiliza $this->pdo e não usa o global $pdo.

Agora, se você cria o $pdo fora da classe, você pode implmementar como um parâmetro do construtor da classe

```
class Usuario {
var $pdo;
public __construct($pdo) { $this->pdo = $pdo; }
}
```

Então, ao criar o objeto:

```
$usr = new Usuario($pdo);
```

Assim você evita usar o global, que não parece uma boa prática para OOP.